# How to create a string with values of previous row SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table with list of account numbers bucket n monthperiod. I need to make a bucket string like below..please help (base SAS)

```
ACC Bucket Month bucketstring
123      0        jan18     0
123       1        feb18   10
123        2       mar18  210
345       0        feb18    0
345       1        mar18  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retain` statement is used to maintain the value of a non-set variable over the iterations of the implicit loop that happens during the `DATA` step.

This example will work with `ACC` groups having upto 15 months (0..15).  ACCs with more months will see a message `put` in the log.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by ACC;

  length bucketstring $20; * bucketstring might have to be made longer;
  retain buckstring;

  if length (bucketstring) = 20 and not first.ACC then
    put 'ERROR: bucketstring has to be longer for the case of ' ACC= month=;

  if first.ACC
    then bucketstring = cats(month);
    else bucketstring = cats(bucketstring,month);
run;
```

The `cats` function concatenates items.  The items are automatically stripped of leading and trailing spaces, as well as automatically converting a number-item to a character value if necessary.